# How to merge java.io.Reader's or wrap Reader's content?

Tags: java, escaping, xss, freemarker

I am wrapping Freemarker template loader in Spring MVC as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1678940/1307586) to have default escaping in html pages.

So, I need to wrap content from java.io.Reader with my strings, not reading it, not converting it to string and not implementing myself. Is there class similar to [WrappingReader](http://metadata-net.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/metadata-net/shared/trunk/util/src/main/java/au/edu/uq/itee/maenad/util/WrappingReader.java?revision=1132&view=markup) or com.google.common.io.MultiReader (which is not public) in popular common libraries?

My implementation:

```
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;
import com.google.common.io.InputSupplier;

...

private final TemplateLoader delegate;

@Autowired
public HtmlEscapingTemplateLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader)
{
    delegate = new SpringTemplateLoader(resourceLoader, "/WEB-INF/templates/");
}

@Override
public Reader getReader(Object templateSource, String encoding) throws IOException
{
    // collecting readers
    Reader prologue = new StringReader("<#escape x as x?html>");
    Reader originalReader = delegate.getReader(templateSource, encoding);
    Reader epilogue = new StringReader("</#escape>");

    // concatenating readers
    return merge(prologue, originalReader, epilogue);
}


protected Reader merge(Reader prologue, Reader originalReader, Reader epilogue) throws IOException
{
    return CharStreams.join(
            Arrays.asList(new ReaderSupplier(prologue), new ReaderSupplier(originalReader), new ReaderSupplier(
                    epilogue))).getInput();
}

private static class ReaderSupplier
        implements InputSupplier<Reader>
{

    private final Reader reader;

    public ReaderSupplier(Reader reader)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public Reader getInput() throws IOException
    {
        return reader;
    }

}
```

CharStreams i use is marked as @com.google.common.annotations.Beta. So, could it be rewritten in more solid way without usage of CharStreams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava contributor here.  ...Okay.

[`@Beta` does not mean "not fully tested" or "not widely used."](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PhilosophyExplained#Iteration)  The only thing it means is that we're not *quite* sure we're ready to freeze the API.  That's only a problem if you're developing a library, or planning to upgrade versions of Guava later.  (Also, honestly, `CharStreams` is about as stable as `@Beta` APIs get...)

You should *not* have a `ReaderSupplier` class, which defeats the whole point of the `InputSupplier` interface.  For this particular case, instead of passing around `Reader`s, you should be passing around `InputSupplier<Reader>`s.  In this particular case, `CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(String)` returns an `InputSupplier` that produces `StringReader`s, so that fits this use case perfectly.

In any event, my complete implementation would be something like:

```
static final String prologue = "<#escape x as x?html>";
static final String epilogue = "</#escape>";

// ideally you shouldn't be passing around Readers at all
// the point of InputSupplier, etc. is that you should never get direct access
// to the Reader directly, so you don't have to track whether it's closed or not
public InputSupplier<Reader> getReaderSupplier(
    final Object templateSource, final String encoding) {
  return CharStreams.join(
    CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(prologue),
    new InputSupplier<Reader>() {
      public Reader getInput() {
        return delegate.getReader(templateSource, encoding);
      }
    },
    CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(epilogue));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Louis, now I understand the idea behind InputSupplier and can eliminate my own invalid implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I am only answering the question: How to merge java.io.Reader's.

Using plain Java I was able to come up with the solution of using `SequenceInputStream` on `InputStreams`, which seems to be the better solution for merging two `InputStreams`. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295099/how-to-chain-multiple-different-inputstreams-into-one-inputstream/38399585) for merging InputStreams.
Idea is simple: convert readers into `InputStreams`, merge those and save the `InputStream` into a `Reader`.

```
Reader reader1 = new StringReader("String1");
Reader reader2 = new StringReader("String2");

ReaderInputStream readInputStream1 = new ReaderInputStream(reader1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
ReaderInputStream readInputStream2 = new ReaderInputStream(reader2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Reader merged = new InputStreamReader(new SequenceInputStream(readInputStream1,readInputStream2), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```