# Spring Boot Freemarker - html escaping by default

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker

Is there any convenient way to enable html escaping by default for all freemarker templates when using spring boot autoconfiguration?

If not, what's proper way to add any of following solutions (keeping spring boot autoconfiguration defaults except of template loader)?

- [Default escaping in Freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265488/default-escaping-in-freemarker)
- http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/default-html-escape-using-freemarker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After following ddekany's advice to use 2.3.24 here's solution:

Modify all template names to .ftlh (required by freemarker to automatically turn on HTML escaper) - including spring.ftl if it's being used. Updated spring.ftlh migh need some '?no_esc' additions for attributes

Adjust freemarker config to use those files:

```
spring.freemarker.suffix=.ftlh
spring.freemarker.settings.recognize_standard_file_extensions=true
```

Modify pom.xml to use freemarker 2.3.24:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
  <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
  <version>freemarker-2.3.24-pre01</version>
</dependency>
```

Following solution is to use local JAR file because 2.3.24 is not yet on maven:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="freemarker-2.3.24-pre01.jar" -DgroupId="org.freemarker" -DartifactId="freemarker" -Dversion="freemarker-2.3.24-pre01" -Dpackaging=jar
```

Voila, automatic freemarker HTML escaping for Spring Boot ;)

Comment: Just a minor clarification: Using `ftlh` extension is the recommended solution, but it's not strictly required by FreeMarker. You can associate arbitrary template name (template path) patterns to `OutputFormat`-s (which specifies the escaping rules) using the `template_configurers` setting.

Comment: How or where do you set "recognize_standard_file_extensions"?

Comment: @efaj to answer myself, it's on the FreeMarkerConfigurer, and if setting beans through xml, set it as a property under <property name="freemarkerSettings">

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker 2.3.24 has auto-escaping as core feature, though when I write this it's not yet released. Until that (1-2 mongth I guess), 2.3.24-pre01 is downloadable from the homepage, or you can build the 2.3-gae branch head (though not much has changed if you are only using auto-escaping among the 2.3.24 features). Auto-escaping is currently described there: http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/builds/2.3.24-pre01/_html/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html

If you can't use 2.3.24 in this form, as the first post you have linked describes, you can use a custom `TemplateLoader`. As `templateLoader` (`template_loader`) is just a FreeMarker configuration setting, hopefully it can be set in Spring too.